# How to use multiple sub-query left join in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am having four table i need to join all the four table in my rails model How can i do it

My Join sample schema is

```
select * from
(
select id,name from table1
)a
left join
(
select * from table2
)b
on a.id=b.user_id
left join
(
select * from table3
)c
on a.id=b.ord_id
left join
(
select * from table4
)d
on a.id=d.other_id
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best features of rails is that you don't have to worry much about writing these types of database setups.  I think you would be very well served by going through the intro to ActiveRecord:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

ActiveRecord abstracts the SQL up one layer, so you're (in theory) not writing any database-specific code.  It also allows you to conceptualize your database schema at a higher level, rather than simply doing left join, inner join, etc.  See here for more info on the various associations:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html